# Polymer 2.0: Notify and reflect to attribute

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm new to this framework and would love to see some useful and simple examples of notify and reflect to attribute properties being put to use.
Please keep the examples simple or add explanation for whatever code you provide.

Answer (score 5):

**Notify:**

can be set to True|False. Let's say you have `parent-element` and `child-element`. Working example

parent-element.html:

```
<dom-module id="parent-element">
  <template>
    <child-element foo="{{test}}"></child-element>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "parent-element",
      properties: {
        test: {
          value: "bar"
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

As you can see, we have 1 property called `test` which is propagated to child element, where we can manipulate with it.

child-element.html:

```
<dom-module id="child-element">
  <template>
    <paper-input value="{{test}}"></paper-input>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'child-element',

      properties: {
        test: {

        }
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

What is hapenning? In child element we defined `test` property and this property is binded to `paper-input`, which means, whenever we write something in `paper-input`, the property updates itself automatically . YEE that's awesome, we don't need to take care of updating property inside `child-element`, but HOW can parent know that property `test` has changed? Well, he can't.

And here comes `notify: true`. If you set it up, you don't have to care about notifying `parent-element` that somewhere inside of the `child-element`, `test` property has been changed.

Shortly, property `test` in `parent-element` and `child-element` will updates simultaneously

**Reflect-to-attribute:**

As name already says, when you set this to some property, it's value will be visible in attribute of host element. Better to show this on some example.

In `Polymer` we know, that setting some binding to attribute of some element needs `$` sign.

```
<custom-elem foo-attribute$="[[someProperty]]"></custom-elem>
```

Well, this can't be used everywhere. Let's say, that we need `foo-attribute` inside `custom-elem`.

Becuase `foo-attribute` was declared as attribute and not property, it's value won't be visible inside of element. So we need something where some attribute will represent attribute and also property.

So some working example, with some real situation would be like:

```
<dom-module id='parent-element'>
  <template>
    <style>
       child-elemet[foo='bar'] {background-color: green}
       child-element[foo='foo'] {background-color: red}
    </style>
    <child-element foo="{{test}}"></child-element>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "parent-element",
      properties: {
        test: {
          value: "bar"
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

In this case, CSS won't work, because `foo` is property (not an attribute) and CSS is applied on attributes only.

To make it work, we have to add `reflectToAttribute` on `foo` property inside `child-element`.

```
<dom-module id='child-element'>
  <template>
    <div>[[foo]]</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "child-element",
      properties: {
        foo: {
          reflectToAttribute: true
        }
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

After this, `foo` will become attribute and also property. At this moment, CSS will be applied on `child-element` and we will be able to work with value of `foo` inside `child-element`

Comment: I have a question, I'm also a newbie if you compare that I don't master this Polymer thing yet, but I have been making stuff at work, in short words, how would you describe that the parent-element need to know that child-element have updated the property, in a real-life case why does it need to know?.

Comment: ok I've read these posts:
https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/properties
https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/properties#notify
https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/data-system#data-flow-is-synchronous

So it's supposed to mean that I need to set them all in notify: true, or based on your example which one of "test" properties should be set.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding

> To bind to an attribute, add a dollar sign ($) after the attribute
>   name:
>
> `<div style$="color: {{myColor}};">`
>
> **Two-way bindings** ... property must be set to notify: true.